# In unity I get one more score and I don't know why

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In the the unity project I got one more score when I use the OnCollisionEnter function and even my object (Player) stay still I got one score in the beginning
Here is my Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scorer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        Debug.Log("You've bumped into a thing this many times: ");
    }
}
```

and here is my rustle :

[image]

the first line shouldn't be appear when I go to the play mode

Comment: If the player's collider contacts with the scorer's collider, an OnCollisionEnter will fire at the beginning.

Comment: I add the Scorer's Script to the player but why the score increase when I hit nowhere?How can I fix it to zero?

Comment: does your player collide with the ground? o.O -> [use tags to filter the collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html)

Comment: yes I know the problem is when player hit the ground but how can I set the ground and player and ground collider to stop effecting on the score?

Comment: I already told you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is ground or plane collider
when you use gravity it will bring these kinda problem

- if you know how to code you should use tag for score object
- if you don't know
  turn off gravity and freeze the position and rotation in a way that you need to.

(these two solution helped me)

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding tags or any other things that can separate score givers and miscellaneous objects. You need to check for them in `OnCollisionEnter` message for other collider being an actual score giver. Your player object hits a ground and it adds a point anyways, hence one unneeded score.